# Mongoid unscoped find throws not found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Mongoid document with a default scope in a rails app

```
class Hippy
...
  default_scope ->{ where(deleted_at: nil) }
...
end
```

If I try to find a record with a known id:

```
hippy = Hippy.find('abc123')
```

The record is found as expected. Or if I try to find_by:

```
hippy = Hippy.find_by(id: 'abc123')
```

The record is found as expected.

However, if I try to find the same record without the default scope:

```
hippy = Hippy.unscoped.find('abc123')
```

I get a `Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound` error. This doesn't feel like it should be expected behaviour.

I'm using Mongoid 6.3.0

Comment: Why shouldn't it be an expected behavior?

Comment: Verify the issue occurs on most recent 6.4.x patch release. If it does, please provide a snippet of code including your models and inserts that is runnable and reproduces the problem.